# bash prompt has a unknown prefix

Tags: bash, prompt

console show strange prompt prefix like this:

```
;user@centos:~[user@centos ~]$ echo $PS1
[\u@\h \W]\$ 
;user@centos:~[user@centos ~]$
```

this problem just appear in console, ssh remote login no this problem.

system info:

```
;user@centos:~[user@centos ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
;user@centos:~[user@centos ~]$ echo $0
-bash
```

Comment: Maybe you have characters in your PS1 which are hidden by your echo command. Try `echo -E "$PS1"` and `printf '%s' "$PS1"|od -cx`. Does this reveal anything?

Comment: Also look at your `$PROMPT_COMMAND` string (if it's set).

Comment: @user1934428 these 2 method not show anything

Comment: @Kusalananda $PROMPT_COMMAND string is 
printf "\033]0;%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"
what is this mean

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think it attempts to update the terminal window title to identify the user@hostname:directory, but the console does not support the control code for changing the window title (because the console doesn't have one). It ignores the control code, and the text that was supposed to go into the window title gets prefixed to the prompt instead. Some login script is unconditionally setting the $PROMPT_COMMAND; you should change it to be set only if you're not on the console.

Comment: Just `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: @telcoM you are right, I find this environment variable setting in /etc/profile.d/vte.sh, and solved this problem by Kusalananda 's method.  But strange thing is there was no such problem before.

Comment: Use `rpm -qf /etc/profile.d/vte.sh` to see if the file was added by a RPM package; if not, use `ls -l /etc/profile.d/vte.sh` to see when the file was last modified. Then use `last` to see who might have been logged in at that time...

Comment: @telcoM I look at the date of this file, it is created two weeks ago, Maybe at that time I installed 'GNOME Desktop' led this problem. thanks

Comment: @Kusalananda can you post an answer and i will accept it. thanks